# run script after passing to links (jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery, mobile, load

I want to run a script after a new page will appear.
Doing so:
in index.html (link):

```
<a href="games.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="./images/1.jpg" alt="" width='100'/></a>
```

in games.html, but this code dont'd run:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            update_list_games();
        });
```

and function:

```
function update_list_games(gamer_id)
{
            requestToServer(prefix_server + 'load_games_list.php?gamer_id=' + gamer_id, function(response){
                if (response.data != null)
                {
                    if (games_list == "")
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; ++i)
                        {
                            games_list += "<li class='my_li' onClick=get_game("+i+")><a href='#page3'><img align='left' src='images/"+response.data[i].icon+"' height='45' width='45' style='padding:10px;'/><h3>"+response.data[i].name+"</h3><p>"+response.data[i].description+"</p></li>";
                        }
                        $("#games_list").append(games_list); 
                        $('#games_list').listview('refresh');
                        $('#games_list').addClass('my_li');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(MES_ERR_SERVER_ACCESS);
                }
    });

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects a parameter (gamer_id) but you call it without one. Also there are other variables used (f.e. prefix_server)  and functions called (requestToServer) in the function that seem to be declared in a different scope (globally?), so without knowing them I cannot answer better.

Comment: function update_list_games - work! If open games.html, then function run and return current games, but if use link, then function dont't called.